# IPN Making Multiple Callbacks - Won't Stop

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm testing my IPN callback handler against Paypal sandbox and for the life of me, I cannot determine why it's making multiple callbacks. Been going since last night when I initiated a test purchase.

In the IPN, do I need to send a post back to Paypal after i confirm the transaction telling them the IPN callback was successful?

I checked the IPN history and the IPN keeps retrying. The log shows a HTTP response code of 405 and Delivery Status = Failed

Pls note that the IPN callback method on my site processes the Request fine from Paypal, I get all the variables such as the transaction id, amount, etc...

I'm using MVC, the ActionResult is marked with [HttpPost]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Introducing IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

> **The IPN message authentication protocol consists of four steps:**
>
> 1. PayPal HTTP POSTs an IPN message to your listener that notifies it of an event.
> 2. Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal.
> 3. Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal; the message must contain the same fields (in the same order) as the original message and be encoded in the same way as the original message.
> 4. PayPal sends a single word back - either `VERIFIED` (if the message matches the original) or `INVALID` (if the message does not match the original).
>
> Your listener must respond to every IPN message it gets, whether you take action on it or not. If you do not respond, PayPal assumes the IPN was not received and re-sends it. *Further, PayPal continues to re-send the message periodically until your listener responds, although the interval between retries increases with each attempt. An IPN will be resent for up to four days, with a maximum of 15 retries.*

Hth.

Comment: Thanks! So after I confirm everything on my listener, I post the message back to Paypal. Do you have a sample handy of a post back to Paypal?

Comment: @MikeAnderson See the link for a _lot_ of detail. At the end of the day you send an HTTP POST to them to verify that you've received and successfully processed the IPN. It's sort of your "backup" - if for some reason your environment has issues (down, updating, recycling, etc.), you won't lose important transaction related notifications. They'll retry based on above retry "promise" until you acknowledge. Hth...

Comment: @MikeAnderson Based on your question, I'm assuming you're on ASP.net? If so, your "listener" would likely be a generic handler (ashx) or a Web API endpoint (there is no need for a UI/no `View` needed). You can programmatically POST using standard [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I reviewed that link and looks like they did provide a sample of a postback to Paypal...

paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=19.95..........

Yes I'm using MVC framework...